# How to draw a chart in PHP or Javascript or JQuery from Yahoo Finance CSV api result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv

I want to draw a chart from the following url in either PHP or Javascript or JQuery

> http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=2&b=02&c=2014&d=2&e=30&f=2014&g=w&ignore=d.csv

I can display the results in html using PHP code:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=2&b=02&c=2014&d=2&e=30&f=2014&g=w&ignore=d.csv");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    ob_start();
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $data = ob_get_clean();

    $rows = explode("\n", $data);
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    foreach($rows as $row) {
      echo "<tr>";
      $cols = explode(',', $row);
      foreach($cols as $col)
        echo "<td>$col</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the question, then?

Comment: The question is how to display a chart from that table?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a chart using the service Google Charts.
https://developers.google.com/chart/

Once you download the document, the script must generate URL for service from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest JavaScript as being a great tool for this type of job. There are a number of great libraries you could use. Yahoo's [yui charts](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/charts/) or [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com) if you prefer jQuery.

Personally I'd recommend Scott Murray's "Interactive Data Visualization for the Web" as a good place to start, you can buy it in print or view it online [free](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/index.html). It is a guided walkthrough, building up to some very complex examples, of the [d3.js](http://d3js.org). To quote from Murray:

> - Loading data into the browser’s memory
> - Binding data to elements within the document, creating new elements as needed
> - Transforming those elements by interpreting each element’s bound datum and setting its visual properties accordingly
> - Transitioning elements between states in response to user input

If you want to get further I recommend, D3's creator, Bostock's tutorials on [github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials).

Comment: JQPlot seems quite easy and straight forward. It would really help me if you could provide some help on how to access columns from the output, e.g. I want to access the "Date" I tried something like $rows[0][0] but it did not work.

Comment: Actually I want to parse data from the table to JQPlot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) for doing this with PHP only. You can find a simple complete implementation example in https://github.com/ivanrodriguez/bresenham-dda-php/blob/master/grafica.php

In your case Date could be X (you need to map dates to numerical values) and you would graph Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj Close as Y values each in different lines on the same graph.